# SQL to give X records after specified record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to write a SQL statement that retrieves X consecutive records after a record with criteria Y, from a list with criteria Z?

for example, given this table :

```
id  name
------------------------------
1   aaa
5   bbb
10  ccc
15  ddd
20  eee
25  fff
30  ggg
```

I first apply criteria Z, something like

```
SELECT * WHERE (id>4) AND (id<26) ORDER BY id ASC
```

then I am left with a list:

```
id  name
------------------------------
5   bbb
10  ccc
15  ddd
20  eee
25  fff
```

I want to know if it's possible to retrieve 2 records from this list from where name='ddd' (or some other criteria Y), ie, to return the "ddd" and "eee" records in the above example.

It must possible to do this directly in SQL, but I'm afraid I lack the mileage to know it.

Comment: perhaps with a combination of COUNT(), OFFSET(), and LIMIT() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE id > 4 
  AND id < 26 
  AND id >= ( SELECT min(id) 
              FROM yourTable
              WHERE id > 4 
                AND id < 26 
                AND name = 'ddd'
            ) 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 2
;
```

In your wording:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE ( criterionZ )
  AND sortingField >=
            ( SELECT min(sortingField ) 
              FROM yourTable
              WHERE ( criterionZ )
                AND ( criterionY )
            ) 
ORDER BY sortingField
LIMIT X
;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the more generic pseudo version, very helpful

Comment: NOTE: if we are sorting DESC instead of ASC, the min() should be a max(), and the >= becomes <=

Comment: Yes, `MAX` instead of `MIN` and `<=` instead of `>=`: `...sortingField <= ( SELECT MAX(...`

Comment: actually it's not perfect, because there might be duplicate values when selecting sortingField, whereas criterionY is meant to specify a unique record only

Comment: @ypercube yes I meant duplicate names (sorry)

Comment: My answer as it is now `retrieves X consecutive records after the **first** record with criteria Y (including this first record), from a list with criteria Z`.  What would you like to happen when there are duplicate names (like `ddd`) in list with criteria Z?

Answer (score 1):

Add limit clause

```
SELECT * WHERE (id>4) AND (id<26) ORDER BY id ASC limit 2,2
```

edit.

```
select * from table where id > (
select id from table where name = 'eee' ) 
order by id
limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the presumption your id numbers are sequential you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name =  'ddd' LIMIT 1) LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This does take into account the *"criteriaZ"*. It would give wrong results if for example first row had `id=1, name='ddd'`. If you add the `AND id>4 AND id<26` in the subquery, and add an `ORDER BY` in the outer query, then it's 99% correct.